# Catch Cross origin issue in java

Tags: java, urlconnection

I would like to verify is some url is valid(MalformedURLException,IOException ). 
I need also check are there any cross origin issue before do some action?

```
URL url = new URL(location);
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
```

Comment: is this in an applet or javafx or something like that?

Comment: This is spring.

Comment: Are you trying to return url to UI, which later does the redirection?

Comment: Actually if this url is right, I would like to load iframe by this url. And In some cases when url has cross origin issue I cannot catch

Comment: isn't this something that should be dealt with on the front end?

Comment: @MK. exactly my thoughts.

Comment: well, it sounds like the backend is deciding what to load and we want to predict on the backend whether loading is going to be legal before asking front end to load it.  However important things seem to be missing here -- I think anything can be loaded into iframe always.  Cross origin kicks in when you try to invoke scripts in that page.  So we need to understand better what is going on here.